# React with redux manage state form data entry fields

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have form with search criteria and result table. we have implemented redux. so the search will go through reducers and return the updated state with response.

Do we need to keep the property of search criteria (name, number) also be part of the redux state ? if so how we handle the `onChange` input fields.

Else still need to keep the local state and `onChange` will handle using `setState`  for input form fields?

I am looking for right approach, where we need to keep the input form fields value in redux state/local state

Comment: some people use [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/). I think local state will work fine so long as you don't need to propagate the field data anywhere else in the app except for that encapsulated component.

Comment: If the rest of the app doesn't need to know what's going on in this component, don't bother putting it in the store. Local state is sometimes absolutely okay: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367